# Suppress delimiters in Ruby's String#split

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, split

I'm importing data from old spreadsheets into a database using rails.

I have one column that contains a list on each row, that are sometimes formatted as

```
first, second
```

and other times like this

```
third and fourth
```

So I wanted to split up this string into an array, delimiting either with a comma or with the word "and".  I tried

```
my_string.split /\s?(\,|and)\s?/
```

Unfortunately, as the docs say:

> If pattern contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in the array as well.

Which means that I get back an array that looks like

```
[
[0] "first"
[1] ", "
[2] "second"
]
```

Obviously only the zeroth and second elements are useful to me.  What do you recommend as the neatest way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Use `(?:…)` to group without capturing.

Comment: You could also just remove the offending delimiters `mystring.gsub(/(,|and)/, '').split`.

Comment: @ptd Then there would be no way to tell the difference between delimited items. Why not substitute the and for a comma delimiter and then run your split?

Comment: Note that your code will split `random` into `r`, `and` and `om`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instruct the regexp to not capture the group using `?:`.

```
my_string.split(/\s?(?:\,|and)\s?/)
# => ["first", "second"]
```

As an aside note

> into a database **using rails**.

Please note this has nothing to do with Rails, that's Ruby.

Comment: I'm glad you provided a Ruby-only solution, but I mentioned Rails because a Rails-only one would have been acceptable.

Comment: what's wrong with matching `'first, second'.scan(/^[^,\s]+|\S+$/)` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj the user mentioned that the strings sometimes contain the comma, other times the AND.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti it works for both. It works only if the strings are in the format that was mentioned above.

Comment: @Dan, "because a Rails-only one would have been acceptable." There is no such thing as a "Rails-only one" when you're talking about Ruby vs. Rails. Rails *IS* Ruby code so you can't separate it from Ruby. Now, it's possible to separate Ruby from Rails though.